# Windows CE internals, TEB (Thread Environment Block)

Tags: c++, c, windows-mobile, internals

I'm not sure if it's a good place to ask such a question.
I'm trying to port some low level library (dbghelp) to wince and I need access to some api that aren't available on wince.
I need to access TEB (Thread Environment Block). There are a couple of API's available on PC that do that, but there is no such thing on WinCE.
One of them is called NTQueryThreadInformation or something like that, and the other one is NtCurrentTEB which returns pointer to TEB for the current thread.
Any pointers on that?..
thanks

Comment: Why are you tagging this as windows-mobile instead of windows-ce while you're mentioning Windows CE?

Answer (score 1):

You can find available CE5 Process and Thread Functions [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa450760.aspx).

Even though no direct equivalent for TEB in WinCE, I have seen TlsGetValue, TlsSetValue, etc for thread local storage, which may be similar to "TEB.TlsSlots". CeGetThreadQuantum, GetThreadTimes, GetThreadPriority and GetThreadContext can also give certain information about the thread.

For myself, I've never used them before since my programming needs usually were satisfied with CreateThread, Suspend/ResumeThread, ThreadProc and Set/GetThreadPriority.

Comment: Off course I reviewed all the MSDN info on threading API in Windows CE. The reason that I need access to TEB is that the dll that I was trying to port does some stuff with the TEB. Basically, I took code from WINE's implementation of dbghelp.dll and wanted to port it to Windows CE (Microsoft doesn't provide CE port of the dll). The dll allows to access debug symbols, get runtime call stack etc, which would be nice to have it in Windows CE apps as well.

Answer (score 0):

[This assembly fragment from Boost.Context](https://github.com/boostorg/context/blob/5d4c593837801040dcb753ba1a3747d3ad797f1e/src/asm/jump_arm_aapcs_pe_armasm.asm#L37) suggests that the TIB pointer is stored in a co-register processor and can be retrieved like this:

```
mrc p15, #0, v1, c13, c0, #2
```

As for the layout of the Thread Information/Environment Block: I'm not sure that it's exactly the same as on Win32. The linked code from Boost definitely seems to assume that to be the case. I haven't been able to find any information confirming the existence of the "deallocation stack" they're (re)storing there. The stack base and limit do appear at those offsets in the WinCE SDK headers.